# Double basses - C extension v 5 strings v neither

Tags: orchestral-strings, 5-string-bass-guitar

This is a curiosity of mine.  Each time I attend a concert, I look at the double basses to see whether they have either a C extension, 5 strings, or neither.  For the concerts that I have attended in the UK, the answer seems to be mostly C extension.  However, on TV or discs, I see 5 strings occasionally; I think (not claim) that this seems to be more common in Germany.

What are the pros and cons?

Is the extra string always C to just enable an octave below the cello or is it sometimes B to retain the spacing?

Also what music requires it or may use it?  I have not noticed notes below the standard 4 string bass being used in concerts that I have attended but, of course, my musical tastes and powers of observation might be the explanation.

Answers on 5 strings bass guitars are also welcome.  I get the impression that the extra string is more commonly B on these.

Comment: I'd be interested to find out what the string spacings are on 4 and 5 double basses. On bass guitars, there seems to be a choice between 5 strings squashed into 4 string necks, and wider necks allowing the same spacing between strings for 5, as the 4 has. It may make bowing slightly tricky, don't know.

Comment: The bowing issue may explain why the C extension seems more popular.  It has a capo like device which can be locked at each of the extension notes.  So, it could be locked at E and then I expect that it can be played like a standard bass.  On the downside, when the lower notes are needed, I guess that the fingering is a little awkward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Five-string basses in orchestra would be tuned BEADG (from low to high). Another option, which would be used more for solo work, would be EADGC, with the fifth string being an additional higher string instead of a lower one.

There are a number of pieces that call for (explicitly or implicitly) lower notes than the typical 4-string bass can play. 
Schubert's 8th symphony has a falling bass line down to a low C in the cello score, but for the bass score, the last two notes, the D and C are written up an octave. Most recordings include the implied notes using either 5-string basses or basses with extensions. I've heard a recording of Rachmaninov's Rhapsody on a Theme by Paganini in which there are clearly basses playing pizzicato on a low B. I imagine a lot of newer music takes advantage of this capability, as these basses become more popular and accessible.

Pros for extensions:

- Extended range while keeping the same neck width
- They can be retroactively added to 4-string basses with minimal
  modifications

Cons for extensions:

- More awkward fingering on lower notes, though some basses have
  special mechanisms to help deal with that
- Adding an extension requires drilling a hole through the scroll, as
  well as mounting the extension to the bass, so if it is ever removed,
  the bass will be marred

Pros for 5-string basses:

- Even more extended range down to B
- More natural fingering, just an additional string
- The bass is often designed with 5 strings in mind, so it is a more
  natural fit

Cons for 5-string basses:

- The fingerboard is wider, which may make for difficult fingering for those with smaller hands
- Bowing may be trickier
- Unless the bass is purpose built for 5 strings, it may not be large
  enough or have big enough components to fully support the low notes

Comment: Retrofitting 5 strings to a 4 string bass had not occurred to me.  I knew that the extensions were often added but I expected that 5 string basses were built that way.

Comment: I don't think it's common, and it is definitely not preferred. However, I was more referring to using the same body design but putting 5 strings on it during manufacture, so widening the neck, different scroll design for 5 tuners, etc, but the body isn't larger, the bass bar, etc aren't beefier, so the sound is less powerful, and the bass may even be weaker.

Comment: Ah, that is easier to see.

Comment: I've used 5 string (eelectric) basses witth 5 strings, that fitted into figerboards designed for 4 strings. They work, but they're certainly not for me. Might work for guitarists who want to be budding bassists.

Comment: It's certainly possible to be far more agile on a low B string than on a C extension. Some C extensions have levers. Others require you to move your hand up to the fingerboard extension. Either way, it's hard to play fast.

Answer (score 4):

I can't can't speak to double basses, but as for bass guitars

> Answers on 5 strings bass guitars are also welcome. I get the impression that the extra string is more commonly B on these.

A 5-string bass guitar typically adds a low B, but I have heard of people using a high C instead. A 6-string bass guitar typically adds both a low B and a high C.

As for usage I see most 5 string players in the metal and jazz genres. Metal because they want the special effect of getting extra low notes. And jazz players like the extra option but tend to use it sparingly. Then there are quite a few people that *think* they want a low B until they realize that it usually sounds a bit floppy and muddy.

Most 6 string players I have seen have been jazz players that like playing solo or with busier chordal passages. The extra range gives you a lot more arrangement options. I personally kind of want a 6 string for this reason—I love playing solo using the upper range of the bass.

Comment: Thanks.  I had forgotten about 6 string basses.

I guess that the extra low string might work better on a double bass since it is larger.  A bass guitar can get away with low notes for its comparatively small size due to its amplification but there may be a limit to the effectiveness of this.

Comment: Yeah a lot of it comes down to string tension. On a typical bass guitar low B, it's just not quite enough. You can mess with string gauges or use a longer scale bass, but I'd guess a lot of that is easier with a double bass.

Answer (score 3):

5 String Double Basses are becoming more popular these days because they've improved the design also they weigh less than a Bass w/ a C Extension.

Comment: You can see that the neck is only a bit bigger than a 4 String Bass, the strings are closer together so that it feels more comfortable to hold, the B String is hanging off the Side, & there's just enough curvature in the bridge to where you can change your bow angles. Thomas George & Martin have really solved the play ability problem w/ 5 String Basses (same goes for basses w/ more strings than that) meaning you can now play Gospel Music in an Unplugged setting.

Comment: As someone who has tried 5 strings, and who actually uses "low G" extension strings (B string extended, not "low C"), I find this video to be the most objective and complete explanation of below-E problems ever put online. You hit every nuance and addressed every problem. Bravo!!

Answer (score 1):

I think 5 string Double Basses are becoming more common these days. Thomas & George Martin cleverly solved the playability problem of the 5 string Double Bass by making some adjustments to the setup which include making the neck & fingerboard a bit wider, having the B string hang off to the side, & increasing the overstand so that the top can be the same thickness, plus it puts the strings further away from the body for easier playabiltiy. How about a Hole-in-the-heart 5 string Double Bass based on a Hole in the Heart Violin to Viola Conversion?[image: hole in the heart idea]

A hole in the heart 5 string Double Bass would be where the function of the soundboard, between the action of the treble bridge  foot and the soundpost is bypassed, this has the effect of reducing the  amplitude of higher frequency resonances, and gives the lower registers  greater sonority.

Comment: Well look right here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSj0SHc0lgA

Answer (score 1):

I've also seen two types of extensions on electric basses:

The "Hipshot", which consists of a tuner with lever to drop the string's tuning by as much as a 4th (depending on string gauge):
[image: hipshot]

(Image from [hipshotproducts.com](https://hipshotproducts.com/products/bt12-bass-xtender))

...and the much rarer Kubicki extension which resembles a shortened version of the extensions seen on string basses, though limited to a maj. 2nd:

[image: Kubicki]

(Image from [thebassgallery.com](https://thebassgallery.com/products/kubicki-ex-factor-bass))

I've not played either (5 strings since 1992), but the Hipshot seems less flexible as you have to keep your thumb against the lever.

The obvious disadvantages to the Kubicki extension are limitation in range and extreme rarity of existence.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer referring to electric basses. As already stated, 5 string basses use either a high C or low B. The low B is more common, as the high C takes the bass into guitar territory. One of the reasons I prefer 5 string is that there is often no need to play on the first few frets, as a lower note is available on that B string. Occasionally, it's nice to finish a song on a root note lower than the usual E, though.

The 6 stringers are often used by jazzers, especially where there's no guitar player, to form partial chords.

As an aside, I used to play with an 8 string player - low F# to high F. Quite interesting!

Comment: An 8 string bass?  That's exotic.  F# nearly an octave below the usual E?  That must be really floppy.  Also close to the limit of our hearing.

Comment: @badjohn - not floppy, just quite thick!  Felt rather than heard.

Comment: I was thinking of user37496's comment that even the more common low B can be floppy.

Comment: Played quite a few 5 strings over several years, and never found a floppy B string. I use .125".

Comment: "there is often no need to play on the first few frets, as a lower note is available on that B string". This what I was referring to as the jazz use-case on either 5 or 6 strings. While metal players specifically want those extra lower notes, jazz players (or anybody playing a lot of changes) tend to just like having more fingering options for the notes that already exist on the E string.

Comment: I have played a standard bass guitar a few times and enjoyed it; I had some lessons from a friend.  I have not tried a 5 string bass but I expect that it would be fun to play with those extra low notes.

Comment: It's a Marmite thing. I actually changed a 4 string so that it has BEAD. That's nice to play, but I then miss the pop-ability of the G string. But it's good for lending out at open mic venues. It gets returned quite soon.